# How to uninstall the files the python3 DMG installer installed?

Tags: macos, uninstallation, python-install

I want to delete what was installed. But I am not sure what was there or what wasn't. What should I delete? I believe it is somewhere in

```
/Library/Frameworks/...
```

but don't really know what I should uninstall. I assume I can also just delete the python 3.2 folder that was added in my applications folder. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the package with Installer.app, as if you were going to reinstall it, there's an option in the menus to show the file list.  Alternatively, you can use the shareware [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) app to investigate the contents of the installer.

Be aware that the file list isn't the whole story.  The package can have scripts that would run which might create or alter files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So it said that it puts the underlying system in here: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework DO I just remove Python.framework then?

Comment: Well, you should make sure that there are no files under that directory other than the ones installed by that package.  For what it's worth, on my Lion 10.7.3 system I have no /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework, so it doesn't appear that the OS has such a thing by default.